# Facing Exception in Liferay: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, dynamicquery

I am having service entity defined in service.xml as below:

`<entity name="LoginData" local-service="true" remote-service="false">
        <!-- PK fields -->
        <column name="userId" type="long" primary="true" />
        <column name="loginDate" type="Date" primary="true" />
 </entity>`

And I am trying to fetch rows using dynamicQuery as defined in LocalServiceImpl class.

`DynamicQuery dynamicQuery=DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(LoginData.class);
 dynamicQuery.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("userId", userId));
 dynamicQuery.add(RestrictionsFactoryUtil.between("loginDate", startDate, endDate));
 return (List<LoginData>)LoginDataLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(dynamicQuery);`

But last line in above code throws exception as

`Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userId of:   com.example.model.impl.LoginDataImpl`

Can someone tell me what is wrong here? OR I am missing anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to write it as 
primaryKey.userId, as you have defined the userid as Primary key so, hibernate expect the userid prefixes with primaryKey.

Comment: Thanks @Danish, it worked. loginDate also requires primaryKey as prefix.